Decimal point issue when migrating data from Oracle to SQL Server using SSIS
I have a simple ETL in SSIS to copy data from Oracle view to a table in SQL Server.
I am using ADO NET as source and OLE DB as destination. I have some columns in Oracle with data type NUMBER that I am copying into SQL Server columns of type Float.
I am using round function for all NUMERIC columns as SSIS was throwing overflow errors and when I click 'preview' all looks fine. Numbers have decimal point and are rounded to 8 places as desired.
When I copy data into SQL Server table, all numbers in float columns are integers without decimal point at all... Not sure what the issue here may be.
I was trying to use Data Conversion to convert NUMBER data types to Decimal and it all looked good in the preview but the issue at the end was the same.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

It is better to use NUMERIC(...) data type on the SQL Server side. FLOAT is an imprecise data type for values like π (3.14159...), etc.

@YitzhakKhabinsky SSIS threw warning that there is possible data loss and cou;dn't finish it. I tried Data Conversion to decimal first but it didn't help.

Solution to the issue was casting oracle values as number in source.
What's interesting is that another solution that worked was to specify N number of rows to fetch in source (worked even without cast function).
